# Angular - Split one array into 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My data looks like this...

```
[{"max":22.625,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451433600000","$priority":null},
{"max":24.5,"min":18.5,"$id":"1451520000000","$priority":null},
{"max":24.125,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451606400000","$priority":null},
{"max":21.5,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451692800000","$priority":null},
{"max":85,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451779200000","$priority":null}]
```

Here we can see 5 sets of data, and I need to be able to split them into 3 arrays.

The first array needs to have all the Max values.

```
22.625, 24.5, 24.125, 21.5, 85
```

The second needs to have all the Min values

```
18.625, 18.5, 18.625, 18.375, 18.375
```

And the last needs to have all the id's

```
1451433600000, 1451520000000, 1451606400000, 1451692800000, 1451779200000
```

Keeping them in the same order is important and if there is multiple duplicate values then I need to keep them.

Im getting the data with angular fire like this...

```
var ref_day = new Firebase("https://mydb.firebaseio.com/1day");
$scope.day_log = $firebaseArray(ref_day);

angular.forEach($scope.day_log, function(value, key){

// I NEED SOME HELP HERE

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and then its super easy:

```
myArray = [{"max":22.625,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451433600000","$priority":null},
    {"max":24.5,"min":18.5,"$id":"1451520000000","$priority":null},
    {"max":24.125,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451606400000","$priority":null},
    {"max":21.5,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451692800000","$priority":null},
    {"max":85,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451779200000","$priority":null}];

maxs = _.map(myArray, function(item) { return item.max }); // [22.625, 24.5, 24.125, 21.5, 85]
mins = _.map(myArray, function(item) { return item.min }); // [18.625, 18.5, 18.625, 18.375, 18.375]
ids = _.map(myArray, function(item) { return item.$id }); // ["1451433600000", "1451520000000", "1451606400000", "1451692800000", "1451779200000"]
```

You can also use native Javascript:

```
maxs = myArray.map(function(item) { return item.max }); // [22.625, 24.5, 24.125, 21.5, 85]
mins = myArray.map(function(item) { return item.min }); // [18.625, 18.5, 18.625, 18.375, 18.375]
ids = myArray.map(function(item) { return item.$id }); // ["1451433600000", "1451520000000", "1451606400000", "1451692800000", "1451779200000"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for your problem.

```
var data = [
    {"max":22.625,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451433600000","$priority":null},
    {"max":24.5,"min":18.5,"$id":"1451520000000","$priority":null},
    {"max":24.125,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451606400000","$priority":null},
    {"max":21.5,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451692800000","$priority":null},
    {"max":85,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451779200000","$priority":null}
];

var minList = [];
var maxList = [];
var $idList = [];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    minList.push(data[i].min);
    maxList.push(data[i].max);
    $idList.push(data[i].$id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.max = $scope.min = $scope.ids = [];

 angular.forEach($scope.day_log, function(v, key) {
   $scope.max.push(v.max);
   $scope.min.push(v.min);
   $scope.ids.push(v.$id)
 });
```

Or using Vanilla JavaScript

```
$scope.max = $scope.day_log.map(function(v, i) {
  return v.max
});
$scope.min = $scope.day_log.map(function(v, i) {
  return v.min
});
$scope.ids = $scope.day_log.map(function(v, i) {
  return v.$id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    {"max":22.625,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451433600000","$priority":null},
    {"max":24.5,"min":18.5,"$id":"1451520000000","$priority":null},
    {"max":24.125,"min":18.625,"$id":"1451606400000","$priority":null},
    {"max":21.5,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451692800000","$priority":null},
    {"max":85,"min":18.375,"$id":"1451779200000","$priority":null}
];
var minList = [];
var maxList = [];
var idList = [];

angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
   minList.push(value.min);    
   maxList.push(value.max);
   idList.push(value.$id);
 });
```

This is also solution.